# Volume integral in $R^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**Compute the volume of the body defined by the inequalities $$x^2+y^2 \leq 4x, \, |z| \leq x^2+y^2 \\$$** 
I write the first inequality as $(x-2)^2+y^2 \leq 4$ so it is a disk with radius $2$ and centrum in $(2,0)$. The second inequality is a paraboloid but I don't see how the absolute value of $z$ affects the figure. If $z^+ \leq x^2+y^2$ then $z^- \leq z^2+y^2$ so I don't see the difference it makes. Also, what method is preferable when computing this type of body? As a difference between two double integrals?

Comment: The absolute value affects it, without it all negative values of $z$ would be okay

Answer (score 2):

The inequality containing absolute value can be transformed to 
$$-(x^2+y^2)\leq z\leq x^2+y^2$$

Because of symmetry, the volume is twice of the object formed between $z=0$ and $z=x^2+y^2$.

Use polar coordinate because the integration region is a circle.